# jquery $ajax not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have to do a cross-domain request and fetch content from a url using $.ajax function.
But the below code only displays the first alert i.e alert(myUrl),
After that the execution stops.The second alert is not displayed. I don't know what is wrong with the code i have written.
Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong here?Thanks in advance.

```
function getContentFromUrl(){
    var myUrl="http://icant.co.uk";
    alert(myUrl);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +
             "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" +
             encodeURIComponent(myUrl) + "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            alert("***********"+data.results[0]);
            if (data.results[0]) {
                var htmlText = data.results[0];
            var jsonObject = parseAndConvertToJsonObj(htmlText);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("displayerrors").innerHTML = "Could not load the page.";
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            document.getElementById("displayerrors").innerHTML = "Could not load the page.";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You forgot to indent your code properly...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery ajax cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` here is not defined

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" + "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(myUrl) + "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
```

and you forget to add a param for the callback function

```
success: function (data) {
    ....
}
```

The finally code should like this

```
function getContentFromUrl() {
        var myUrl = "http://icant.co.uk";
        alert(myUrl);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" + "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(myUrl) + "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                alert("***********" + data.results[0]);
                if (data.results[0]) {
                    var htmlText = data.results[0];
                    var jsonObject = parseAndConvertToJsonObj(htmlText);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("displayerrors").innerHTML = "Could not load the page.";
                }
            },
            error: function () { document.getElementById("displayerrors").innerHTML = "Could not load the page."; }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have test it, just paste my code and it works, make sure function  `parseAndConvertToJsonObj` is defined in your code.

Comment: But now i have another problem. First time i call this it gives data.results[0] is undefined. But second time it get the html.

Comment: Yes it is defined and also the alert("***********" + data.results[0]); is before calling the function parseAndConvertToJsonObj() so the error is before that is my assumption.

Comment: Sorry I dont know what are you talking about exactly.

Answer (score 6):

[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites.

Comment: Yes but according to this tutorial we can use getJSON function. http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax  and i tried to convert getJSON to $.ajax so the function ended like this.

Comment: I tried to convert in into $ajax because it has more flexibilty than getJSON

Comment: @user1536201 - I hate to solicit my answer on another perfectly good answer, but if you want to use JSONP with the `$.ajax` method, you should just add the two parameters that are in my answer. jQuery takes care of nearly everything else, so it's not actually that difficult. If you're having trouble, please specify what, exactly, is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use regular JSON for cross-domain requests because of the same-origin policy. Instead, you'll need to use JSONP. In jQuery, you can do so like this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true
    // other info
});
```

Note that there are security issues involved with JSONP. Only use JSONP if you trust the host domain.

Comment: Yes, that is the best method of approach.

Comment: There is a `callback=?` in his url, jQuery will take this as a jsonp request automatically.

Comment: But he specifically states `dataType: 'json'`. Doesn't that override the jQuery automatic type detection?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's correct. Anyways, it's best to be specifically state what data type to use.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is jQuery?

Try the following:

```
url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +"q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(myUrl) + "%22&format=xml'&callback=?";
getContentFromURL(url);

function getContentFromURL(url)
{
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

If it dumps out to the console a response, you can build from there.

Comment: He has a jQuery tag and is using jQuery code, so yes, that would be a logical assumption. =p